# React Nativa FlatList can't seem to scroll at all

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I had a problem with basic scrolling on a FlatList in one of my projects so I took the basic example from Facebook's page regarding working with lists and I enhanced it with some extra items in the original FlatList so that scrolling can be expected on an actual device:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FlatListBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
            {key: 'Joel'},
            {key: 'John'},
            {key: 'Jillian'},
            {key: 'Jimmy'},
            {key: 'Julie'},
            {key: 'Devin2'},
            {key: 'Jackson2'},
            {key: 'James2'},
            {key: 'Joel2'},
            {key: 'John2'},
            {key: 'Jillian2'},
            {key: 'Jimmy2'},
            {key: 'Julie2'},
          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   paddingTop: 22
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
})
```

Turns out whenever you scroll down after you take the finger up from the screen the List automatically scrolls back up to the starting position. Anything I am doing wrong here or is this somehow the intended behavior after all which means I got the documentation all wrong?

Env:
react-native v. 0.49.1
Both ios and android, virtual and real devices

Comment: Can you add the part of code that you are using this component? Problem might be related to the parent component being re-render and this might cause this component to re-render and scroll to top.

Comment: I will do that tomorrow morning when I get to the work computer / repo, but in the meantime you can check out this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-listview.html - first example running in expo. it's the same as what I wrote, only that there are fewer elements being rendered.